# The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: libavcodec.xcframework, libavdevice.xcframework, libavfilter.xcframework

Tags: ios, dart, cocoapods

I'm trying to run a flutter app on ios simulator. But, first I'm trying to run **pod install** command.
Some of the pods get installed but after Installing webview_flutter_wkwebview (0.0.1), I get the error

[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: libavcodec.xcframework, libavdevice.xcframework, libavfilter.xcframework, libavformat.xcframework, libavutil.xcframework, libswresample.xcframework, and libswscale.xcframework.

These are the things I've tried but failed:

1. Flutter Clean and re run after flutter pub get
2. flutter pub get && flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
3. pod deintegrate and pod install
4. Flutter pub cache repair and flutter pub get.

Is there any other solution I can try? Thank You.

Here's my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.1'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? What was the solution?